# ASP.net MVC Routing resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I just cant get this to work...
I have the following routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html|js|css|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{lama}/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", lama = "en-gb" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

And once I load the page.. I have a img element that tries to retrive the following url:
css/img/backgrounds/slide1_2048x1280.jpg

But the image wont show up and if I check my console I get the following error:
GET {my localhost}/cn/Home/css/img/backgrounds/slide1_2048x1280.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I have such a hard time understanding the route-system.. is there anywhere I can read ALOT more about this?.. And could somebody please help me with this single problem then that whould be very appreciated!

Comment: Out of the box the MVC project template's default routing will not interfere with URLs that map to files that physically exist.  Do you have `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in there somewhere?

Comment: Hmm... for some wierd reason it seems to work now.. :/...

Comment: Must have been some other wierd problem.. cause if i visit {my localhost}/en-gb.. everything works great.. but if i would visit {my localhost}/en-gb/Home/Index, the image is gone..

Comment: Ah - that's a problem with how you are rendering you img link - you should ideally be using `Url.Content` to generate the correct absolute path to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think have fallen foul of relative urls in your html.

Since you haven't said whether this is Razor or Aspx; I'm just going to go with Aspx.

When you write the `img` tag it seems that you might be doing:

`<img src="[relative_path_to_file]" />`, using the path of the img relative to the page.

If that doesn't start with `/` then it's almost certainly the case that you will end up with issues, especially since MVC URLs don't map to the path of the actual page.

What you want to do is to use `Url.Content("~/[full_path_to_file]")` which will ensure that an absolute path will always be used.

On another note - you really do **not** need to write all these ignore routes for files that exist on disk.  By default, the routing engine will not route existing files - you have to set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in the `RegisterRoutes` method in your global in order to route files that already exist; so I think you should get rid of them.

Comment: How couldnt I see that on myown :), thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

i usually hit up 1) stackoverflow (obviously!), and 2) the msdn docs are pretty good:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410120.aspx. But i usually end up googling for specifically what i need =)

However, looks like you're trying to setup a route to ignore certain filetypes?
i found [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) that gives some good ideas on how to handle this.

I've only blocked one or two filetypes before, and i made one line per filetype. Not sure if you can make one line that has extensions delimited by pipe (|) like you're doing (i could be wrong!)

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allswf}", new {allswf=@".*\.swf(/.*)?"});
```